# JObject to TableView in C#

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, twitter, xamarin

I am trying to parse the Twitter Api with Newtonsoft's Json.net client. But i am getting in trouble when I try to connect the Twitter Cell with the Twitter Data:

**TableSource.cs**

```
public JObject twitterData { get; set; }

if (tableView.ContentSize.Height - UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height <= tableView.ContentOffset.Y) {
        BTProgressHUD.Show ("Getting more...");
        FLDTRequest.getInstagramNextPage (tableView);
        BTProgressHUD.Dismiss ();
    }

    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (TwitterCell.Key) as TwitterCell;

    if (cell == null) {
        cell = new TwitterCell ();
        var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("TwitterCell", cell, null);
        cell = Runtime.GetNSObject (views.ValueAt (0)) as TwitterCell;
    }

    JObject tweet = twitterData[indexPath.Row]; //Error Here: Cannot convert JToken to JObject

    cell.BindData (tweet);
    return cell;
```

**TwitterRequest.cs**

```
IEnumerable<Account> accounts = AccountStore.Create ().FindAccountsForService ("Twitter");


var enumerable = accounts as IList<Account> ?? accounts.ToList ();
if (enumerable.Any ()) {
Account twitter = enumerable.First ();
var twitterOauthToken = twitter.Properties ["oauth_token"].ToString ();
var twitterOauthTokenSecret = twitter.Properties ["oauth_token_secret"].ToString ();
var twitterOauthConsumerKey = twitter.Properties ["oauth_consumer_key"].ToString ();
var twitterOauthConsumerSecret = twitter.Properties ["oauth_consumer_secret"].ToString ();

var request = new RestRequest("1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json");

var client = new RestClient("https://api.twitter.com")
{
    Authenticator = RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(twitterOauthConsumerKey, twitterOauthConsumerSecret, twitterOauthToken, twitterOauthTokenSecret)
};
 client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
        JObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response.Content);
        Console.WriteLine((string)obj["text"]);

            ((TableSource)table.Source).twitterData = rootObject.data;
        });
 }
```

What would be the correct way to display twitter tweets onto a UITableView?

**Edit://**

```
[
  {
    "coordinates": null,
    "truncated": false,
    "created_at": "Tue Aug 28 21:16:23 +0000 2012",
    "favorited": false,
    "id_str": "240558470661799936",
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "entities": {
      "urls": [

      ],
      "hashtags": [

      ],
      "user_mentions": [

      ]
    },
    "text": "just another test",
    "contributors": null,
    "id": 240558470661799936,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "geo": null,
    "retweeted": false,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "place": null,
    "source": "<a href="//realitytechnicians.com\"" rel="\"nofollow\"">OAuth Dancer Reborn</a>",
    "user": {
      "name": "OAuth Dancer",
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
      "profile_background_tile": true,
      "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
      "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/730275945/oauth-dancer_normal.jpg",
      "created_at": "Wed Mar 03 19:37:35 +0000 2010",
      "location": "San Francisco, CA",
      "follow_request_sent": false,
      "id_str": "119476949",
      "is_translator": false,
      "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
      "entities": {
        "url": {
          "urls": [
            {
              "expanded_url": null,
              "url": "http://bit.ly/oauth-dancer",
              "indices": [
                0,
                26
              ],
              "display_url": null
            }
          ]
        },
        "description": null
      },
      "default_profile": false,
      "url": "http://bit.ly/oauth-dancer",
      "contributors_enabled": false,
      "favourites_count": 7,
      "utc_offset": null,
      "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/730275945/oauth-dancer_normal.jpg",
      "id": 119476949,
      "listed_count": 1,
      "profile_use_background_image": true,
      "profile_text_color": "333333",
      "followers_count": 28,
      "lang": "en",
      "protected": false,
      "geo_enabled": true,
      "notifications": false,
      "description": "",
      "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
      "verified": false,
      "time_zone": null,
      "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/80151733/oauth-dance.png",
      "statuses_count": 166,
      "profile_background_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/80151733/oauth-dance.png",
      "default_profile_image": false,
      "friends_count": 14,
      "following": false,
      "show_all_inline_media": false,
      "screen_name": "oauth_dancer"
    },
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null
  },
  {
    "coordinates": {
      "coordinates": [
        -122.25831,
        37.871609
      ],
      "type": "Point"
    },
    "truncated": false,
    "created_at": "Tue Aug 28 21:08:15 +0000 2012",
    "favorited": false,
    "id_str": "240556426106372096",
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "entities": {
      "urls": [
        {
          "expanded_url": "http://blogs.ischool.berkeley.edu/i290-abdt-s12/",
          "url": "http://t.co/bfj7zkDJ",
          "indices": [
            79,
            99
          ],
          "display_url": "blogs.ischool.berkeley.edu/i290-abdt-s12/"
        }
      ],
      "hashtags": [

      ],
      "user_mentions": [
        {
          "name": "Cal",
          "id_str": "17445752",
          "id": 17445752,
          "indices": [
            60,
            64
          ],
          "screen_name": "Cal"
        },
        {
          "name": "Othman Laraki",
          "id_str": "20495814",
          "id": 20495814,
          "indices": [
            70,
            77
          ],
          "screen_name": "othman"
        }
      ]
    },
    "text": "lecturing at the \"analyzing big data with twitter\" class at @cal with @othman  http://t.co/bfj7zkDJ",
    "contributors": null,
    "id": 240556426106372096,
    "retweet_count": 3,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "geo": {
      "coordinates": [
        37.871609,
        -122.25831
      ],
      "type": "Point"
    },
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "place": {
      "name": "Berkeley",
      "country_code": "US",
      "country": "United States",
      "attributes": {
      },
      "url": "http://api.twitter.com/1/geo/id/5ef5b7f391e30aff.json",
      "id": "5ef5b7f391e30aff",
      "bounding_box": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -122.367781,
              37.835727
            ],
            [
              -122.234185,
              37.835727
            ],
            [
              -122.234185,
              37.905824
            ],
            [
              -122.367781,
              37.905824
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      },
      "full_name": "Berkeley, CA",
      "place_type": "city"
    },
    "source": "<a href="//www.apple.com\"" rel="\"nofollow\"">Safari on iOS</a>",
    "user": {
      "name": "Raffi Krikorian",
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
      "profile_background_tile": false,
      "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
      "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1270234259/raffi-headshot-casual_normal.png",
      "created_at": "Sun Aug 19 14:24:06 +0000 2007",
      "location": "San Francisco, California",
      "follow_request_sent": false,
      "id_str": "8285392",
      "is_translator": false,
      "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
      "entities": {
        "url": {
          "urls": [
            {
              "expanded_url": "http://about.me/raffi.krikorian",
              "url": "http://t.co/eNmnM6q",
              "indices": [
                0,
                19
              ],
              "display_url": "about.me/raffi.krikorian"
            }
          ]
        },
        "description": {
          "urls": [

          ]
        }
      },
      "default_profile": true,
      "url": "http://t.co/eNmnM6q",
      "contributors_enabled": false,
      "favourites_count": 724,
      "utc_offset": -28800,
      "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1270234259/raffi-headshot-casual_normal.png",
      "id": 8285392,
      "listed_count": 619,
      "profile_use_background_image": true,
      "profile_text_color": "333333",
      "followers_count": 18752,
      "lang": "en",
      "protected": false,
      "geo_enabled": true,
      "notifications": false,
      "description": "Director of @twittereng's Platform Services. I break things.",
      "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
      "verified": false,
      "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
      "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
      "statuses_count": 5007,
      "profile_background_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
      "default_profile_image": false,
      "friends_count": 701,
      "following": true,
      "show_all_inline_media": true,
      "screen_name": "raffi"
    },
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null
  },
  {
    "coordinates": null,
    "truncated": false,
    "created_at": "Tue Aug 28 19:59:34 +0000 2012",
    "favorited": false,
    "id_str": "240539141056638977",
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "entities": {
      "urls": [

      ],
      "hashtags": [

      ],
      "user_mentions": [

      ]
    },
    "text": "You'd be right more often if you thought you were wrong.",
    "contributors": null,
    "id": 240539141056638977,
    "retweet_count": 1,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "geo": null,
    "retweeted": false,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "place": null,
    "source": "web",
    "user": {
      "name": "Taylor Singletary",
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "FBFBFB",
      "profile_background_tile": true,
      "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
      "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2546730059/f6a8zq58mg1hn0ha8vie_normal.jpeg",
      "created_at": "Wed Mar 07 22:23:19 +0000 2007",
      "location": "San Francisco, CA",
      "follow_request_sent": false,
      "id_str": "819797",
      "is_translator": false,
      "profile_link_color": "c71818",
      "entities": {
        "url": {
          "urls": [
            {
              "expanded_url": "http://www.rebelmouse.com/episod/",
              "url": "http://t.co/Lxw7upbN",
              "indices": [
                0,
                20
              ],
              "display_url": "rebelmouse.com/episod/"
            }
          ]
        },
        "description": {
          "urls": [

          ]
        }
      },
      "default_profile": false,
      "url": "http://t.co/Lxw7upbN",
      "contributors_enabled": false,
      "favourites_count": 15990,
      "utc_offset": -28800,
      "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2546730059/f6a8zq58mg1hn0ha8vie_normal.jpeg",
      "id": 819797,
      "listed_count": 340,
      "profile_use_background_image": true,
      "profile_text_color": "D20909",
      "followers_count": 7126,
      "lang": "en",
      "protected": false,
      "geo_enabled": true,
      "notifications": false,
      "description": "Reality Technician, Twitter API team, synthesizer enthusiast; a most excellent adventure in timelines. I know it's hard to believe in something you can't see.",
      "profile_background_color": "000000",
      "verified": false,
      "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
      "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/643655842/hzfv12wini4q60zzrthg.png",
      "statuses_count": 18076,
      "profile_background_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/643655842/hzfv12wini4q60zzrthg.png",
      "default_profile_image": false,
      "friends_count": 5444,
      "following": true,
      "show_all_inline_media": true,
      "screen_name": "episod"
    },
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null
  }
]
```

Comment: What does twitterData look like?

Comment: @Jason if you are asking this for creating a strongly created class I already have that done.

Comment: @Jason but if you are asking for the JSON I have added it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a Json array, so use `JArray` instead of `JObject`

```
// data is your raw json string
JArray json = JArray.Parse (data);

// json[0] will be first element, json[1] will be second, etc
```